# Cluetip open at the same spot

Tags: jquery, cluetip

Hallo

I am using cluetip and it works perfectly. but I want all the tip to open on the exact samt spot on the site.

my clue tip looks like this atm

```
$('a.btn').cluetip(
   {
     cluetipClass: 'jtip',
    local:true,
    sticky: true,
    dropShadow: false,
    hoverIntent: true,
    closePosition: 'title',
    sticky: true,
    leftOffset: 25, 
    closeText: '<img src="/images/cluetip/cross.png" alt="" />',
    cursor: 'pointer',
   activation: 'click',
   }
 );
```

Comment: I think you'd have to modify the plugin in order to do that; in fact I'm not sure why you'd use cluetip in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole reason of cluetip (besides nice styling) is to have the tooltips pop up relative to the link, so I don't know why you would want the tooltips to open always at the same spot on your site.

But you can achieve this using basic CSS styling for your cluetip class `jtip`:

```
.jtip {
 position: absolute !important;
 left: 20px;
 right: 20px;
}
```

Of course it would be cleaner if you would rewrite the cluetip plugin to not use relative positioning (e.g. see leftOffset), but absolute positioning.